# Python, Automated Array Formation Data Retrieval Error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-retrieval

I am attempting to create a 2d array, and then subsequently pull data from the array and insert data at a specific point in the array. Below is some code that I wrote for creating the 2D Array:

```
from array import *
import math, random

TDArrayBuilder = []
TDArray = []
for yrunner in range(3):
    for xrunner in range(3):
        TDArrayBuilder.append(random.randint(0,1))
    TDArray.insert(yrunner, [TDArrayBuilder])
    TDArrayBuilder = []

print(TDArray[0][2])
```

The Error that this is spitting out is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/TestFile.py", line 13, in 
>   print(TDArray[0][2])
>   IndexError: list index out of range

I also wrote some code previous to this regarding finding and printing the minimum values and maximum values in a 2D array, it was easily able to print the value at the specified location. I'm pretty sure this is just because I used numpy, but I would still like to do this without numpy.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np  #required Import
import math
#preset matrix data
location = []       #Used for locations in searching
arr = np.array([[11, 12, 13],[14, 15, 16],[17, 15, 11],[12, 14, 15]]) #Data matrix
result = np.where(arr == (np.amax(arr)))    #Find the position(s) of the lowest data or the highest data, change the np.amax to npamin for max or min respectively
listofCoordinates = list(zip(result[0], result[1])) #Removes unnecessary stuff from the list
for cord in listofCoordinates:  #takes the coordinate data out, individually
    for char in cord:           #loop used to separate the characters in the coordinate data
        location.append(char)   #Stores these characters in a locator array

length = (len(location))                #Takes the length of location and stores it
length = int(math.floor((length / 2)))  #Floors out the length / 2, and changes it to an int instead of a float
for printer in range(length):           #For loop to iterate over the location list
    ycoord = location[(printer*2)]      #Finds the row, or y coord, of the variable
    xcoord = location[((printer*2)+1)]  #Finds the column, or x coord of the variable
    print(arr[ycoord][xcoord])          #Prints the data, specific to the location of the variables
```

Summary:

I would like to be able to retrieve data from a 2d array, and I don't know how to do that (regarding the first code). I made a file using numpy and it worked, however, I would prefer not to use it for this operation as of current. anything would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

TDArray = list()
for yrunner in range(3):
    TDArrayBuilder = list()
    for xrunner in range(3):
        TDArrayBuilder.append(randint(0, 1))
    TDArray.insert(yrunner, TDArrayBuilder)

print(TDArray)
print(TDArray[0][2])
```

or

```
TDArray = [[randint(0, 1) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
print(TDArray)
print(TDArray[0][2])
```

Comment: Im presuming my error was in attempting to insert the array as a single element using []